# Is elementary OS "ready for prime time?"

Tags: release-hera, system-installation, rdp

I'm considering installing eOS 5.1 (hera) on a Dell server.  I don't want to go down the path of wiping everything on my disks and then discovering that there are incompatibilities.  I already did that with CentOS and Ubuntu 20.04.  I'm currently running LXLE, which is an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS base with an xfce desktop.  So, doing my "due diligence" I have tried the following

- Running the live USB on a Macbook Air
- Running the live USB on my Dell server
- Building and running a VMware VM from the eOS .iso

Of critical importance to me is the ability the remote in using RDP.  To that end, I have installed xrdp (v.0.9.15) on each and every one, and have yet to be able to arrive at the desktop (I am currently using xrdp for my LXLE).  So far...

- The live USB on Mac won't see my wireless card, and I can't connect to my LAN
- The live USB on the server sees my Enet connection, but then balks at xrdp
- The VM locks up on the login screen. The click updates correctly, but no mouse or keyboard input is detected.  Further, I can't send CTRL-ALT-F1 (Option key is ALT on a Mac) with any results.

So, for all intents and purposes, I have now tried three different approaches and have missed the pitch all three times.  That's a strike out in baseball.  Am I wasting my time, and should I look for another distro to use?

Answer (score 1):

Related to RDP, "Remmina Remote Desktop Client" works on ElementaryOS very well!

Answer (score 0):

Genuinely, avoid ElementaryOS if you need RDP - it's not compatible "out of the box" with anything that I have found except x11vnc (that's what I'm using and I'm connecting to a dell 1950)

The issue seems to be Pantheon itself.

If you do want to go down the x11vnc route, this is what I did on 5.1

https://tecadmin.net/setup-x11vnc-server-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/